# Scikit-Learn - Learned model description?

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a way I can "look inside" a model once it's trained? For example, if I train a spam filter with a `multinomialNB`, is there a way I can extract which words are most likely to make an email classify as spam? I'd like to see how the models determine the outcome once fitted.

Comment: I have not worked with multinomialNB before, but I see that it has the coef_ property.  Extracting the model coefficients is one way to 'look inside' the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the particular case of the MultinomialNB you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116697/how-to-get-most-informative-features-for-scikit-learn-classifiers).

However if want you want is to determine which features are the most important, the [SelectFromModel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html) for selecting the most important features for the model.